# in rails how I can calculate number of records of a child table(model) inside the parent frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I have 2 models Project and Task where Project has many tasks 
I want to update the 'progress' in the project frontend with the number of completed tasks

what the best way to do that 
should I create 'progress field' in the project table or it is better to do that in another way

I tried to do this

```
//Project model
def completed_tasks(project)
   self.tasks.where({completed: true}).count
end
```

```
 //Project controller 
def isDone
  @isDone_tasks = Project.completed_tasks(:id)

end
```

Comment: What do you think this: `self.tasks.where({:project_id => project.id}).count` is doing?

Comment: it was suppose to be  self.tasks.where({completed: true}).count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would go about it:

1. I would add add a field called `completed` with boolean type to tasks table, and defaults to `false`
2. If a task is completed, the field is updated to `true`
3. I would modify your `completed_tasks` method:

```
// Project model
def completed_tasks
  tasks.where(completed: true).count
end
```

Note that I removed the `self`. You don't necessarily have to explicitly call that since you are inside the model already.

4. I would modify your `isDone` method, you don't use camelCase naming in Ruby, the convention is to use snake_case.

```
 // Project controller 
def number_of_tasks_done
  project = Project.find(params[:id])
  render json: project.completed_tasks, status: 200
end
```

I'm assuming here that you are sending the `id` of the project from the frontend, and that's what I'm accessing in the params as params[:id], and I'm also assuming that you want to send the response back to the frontend as JSON for processing/display.

Comment: You may want to spend some time on understanding the fundamental of Rails. Like understanding the ActiveRecord Model and how Rails and React interact together.
You can start something from here: https://www.railstutorial.org/

Comment: so for the routes.rb I do this ``` get "/projects/:id/tasksdone" , to: "projects#number_of_tasks_done"``` then I should fetch this: `/projects/${id}/tasksdone`  ?